# How do I get a foreach loop to skip records in an array which have a blank field?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this foreach loop to insert this array into a database.  I want it to skip records that have nothing in the field tr_name.  What's the best way to do that?

```
 foreach($_POST['tr_name'] as $tr_name) {
         $sql3 = "INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES ('".$_POST['game_name']."', '".$tr_name['tr_name']."', '".$tr_name['tr_desc']."', '".$tr_name['tr_color']."', '".$tr_name['tr_ach_value']."')";
        mysql_query($sql3);
```

The data for the field game_name inserted properly. Each of the rest of the fields were filled with only the first character of what was input in the tr_name field.  Why would that happen?

Here's the form:

```
<form action="http://www.yeahthatrocks.com/update.php" method="post">
Game Name:  <input name="game_name" type="text" size="25" maxlength="255" /><br></br>
Release Date:  <input name="release_date" type="text" size="25" /><p></p>

<p>Console:
  <select name="game_console">
    <option value="PS3">PS3</option>
    <option value="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
  </select>

  Game Category:  
  <select name="game_category">
    <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option value="PSN">PSN</option>
    <option value="Arcade">Arcade</option>
    <option value="Arcade">DLC</option>
  </select>

  Game Type:  
  <select name="game_type">
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Action RPG">Action RPG</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
    <option value="Board">Board</option>
    <option value="Card">Card</option>
    <option value="Casino">Casino</option>
    <option value="Educational">Educational</option>
    <option value="Fighting">Fighting</option>
    <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
    <option value="Game Show">Game Show</option>
    <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
    <option value="Music">Music</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Pinball">Pinball</option>
    <option value="Platformer">Platformer</option>
    <option value="Puzzle">Puzzle</option>
    <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
    <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
    <option value="Shooter">Shooter</option>
    <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
    <option value="Virtual Pet">Virtual Pet</option>
  </select>



 Trophy Totals:</p> 

 Bronze:  <input name="bronze_ttl" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" />
 <br/>
Silver:  <input name="Silver Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Gold:  <input name="Gold Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Platinum:  <input name="Platinum Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Hidden:  <input name="Hidden Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Xbox Pts.:  <input name="Xbox Pts Total" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" /><br/>



</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Trophies:</p>
Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[0]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[0]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[0]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[0]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[1]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[1]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[1]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[1]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[2]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[2]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[2]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[2]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[3]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[3]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[3]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[3]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[4]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[4]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[4]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[4]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Problem #1: SQL injection. This code is a gaping security hole.

Comment: I'm aware of the injection issue.  I haven't escaped the inserts yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `continue;` to control your foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST['tr_name'] as $tr_name) {

  if(empty($tr_name)) { continue; }

  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES ('".$_POST['game_name']."', '".$tr_name['tr_name']."', '".$tr_name['tr_desc']."', '".$tr_name['tr_color']."', '".$tr_name['tr_ach_value']."')";
  mysql_query($sql3);
}
```

### **Edit**

Your form would generate 4 standalone arrays each containing 4 items like name, description, color etc. It would look like this:

```
tr_name[0]
tr_desc[0]

tr_name[1]
tr_name[2]

...
```

What you probably want is one array containing 4 inner arrays with 4 items in it like:

```
tr[0][name]
tr[0][desc] 

tr[1][name]
tr[1][desc]
...
```

The new Form:

```
<form action="http://www.yeahthatrocks.com/update.php" method="post">
Game Name:  <input name="game_name" type="text" size="25" maxlength="255" /><br></br>
Release Date:  <input name="release_date" type="text" size="25" /><p></p>

<p>Console:
  <select name="game_console">
    <option value="PS3">PS3</option>
    <option value="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
  </select>

  Game Category:  
  <select name="game_category">
    <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option value="PSN">PSN</option>
    <option value="Arcade">Arcade</option>
    <option value="Arcade">DLC</option>
  </select>

  Game Type:  
  <select name="game_type">
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Action RPG">Action RPG</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
    <option value="Board">Board</option>
    <option value="Card">Card</option>
    <option value="Casino">Casino</option>
    <option value="Educational">Educational</option>
    <option value="Fighting">Fighting</option>
    <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
    <option value="Game Show">Game Show</option>
    <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
    <option value="Music">Music</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Pinball">Pinball</option>
    <option value="Platformer">Platformer</option>
    <option value="Puzzle">Puzzle</option>
    <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
    <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
    <option value="Shooter">Shooter</option>
    <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
    <option value="Virtual Pet">Virtual Pet</option>
  </select>



 Trophy Totals:</p> 

 Bronze:  <input name="bronze_ttl" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" />
 <br/>
Silver:  <input name="Silver Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Gold:  <input name="Gold Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Platinum:  <input name="Platinum Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Hidden:  <input name="Hidden Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Xbox Pts.:  <input name="Xbox Pts Total" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" /><br/>



</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Trophies:</p>
Trophy Name:    <input name="tr[0][name]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr[0][desc]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr[0][color]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr[0][ach_value]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr[1][name]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr[1][desc]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr[1][color]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr[1][ach_value]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


Trophy Name:    <input name="tr[2][name]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr[2][desc]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr[2][color]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr[2][ach_value]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr[3][name]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr[3][desc]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr[3][color]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr[3][ach_value]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr[4][name]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr[4][desc]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr[4][color]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr[4][ach_value]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Your PHP code now should look like:

```
// $_POST['tr'] holds an array with trophies and the trophies' attributes

foreach($_POST['tr'] as $tr) {

  /*
    $tr is now a hash like:

    array( 
      "name" => "a name you entered",
      "desc" => "the description",
      "color" => "black",
      "ach_value" => "a value you entered"
    )

  */

  if(empty($tr['name'])) { continue; }

  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES ('".$_POST['game_name']."', '".$tr['name']."', '".$tr['desc']."', '".$tr['color']."', '".$tr['ach_value']."')";


  mysql_query($sql3);
}
```

Comment: The data for the field game_name inserted properly. Each of the rest of the fields were filled with only the first character of what was input in the tr_name field. Why would that happen?

Comment: hi, I think it fails because your `$tr_name` isn't an array. Do this: before the foreach loop do `print_r($_POST['tr_name']);` and then after `$sql3 = "...";` do this: `print_r($sql3);` maybe you can post the result if you don't know what's wrong

Comment: I believe I did set the array up properly.  I added the form in an edit above.

Comment: you created 4 independent arrays instead of one array holding 4 inner arrays :) see my edit

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(array_filter($_POST['tr_name']) as $tr_name) {
…
```

Comment: This will also be the fastest way of doing it, as it calls `array_filter` which is a C method call!

Good idea Ivan, I'd never thought of doing that!

Comment: Thanks. I just like that "functional" style.

Comment: Something, unfortunately, PHP is still pretty bad in! A lovely language, but still getting it's feet wet in functional terms

Answer (score 1):

Unless tr_name as multiple values (and the HTML is lookling like ) this is the right way. If it only has one value () this is wrong.

Let's stick by thinking you've got multiple input fields. Then this is all you have to do:

```
foreach($_POST['tr_name'] as $tr_name) {
  if($tr_name != "") {
    // insert query
  }
}
```

Comment: tr_name and all the fields that are after it are in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
foreach($_POST['tr_name'] as $tr_name) {
    if (empty($tr_name)) {
        continue;
    }

    // insert query
}
```